# PHPWord: layout topic - calculate content height to determine a necessary pagebreak

Tags: php, docx, phpword, text-rendering

We were publishing our articles (e.g. online courses with description and other details) in a docx formatted document generated with PHPWord. Normally the description and the details dont fill half of a page. Therefore we often put two descriptions onto one page due to layout issues.

PROBLEM:
If a description is longer, we don't want to get a pagebreak within the description; a pagebreak before would be desirable.

*IDEA:
Is it possible to calculate the height of an section (which contains the description and the details) to decide if a pagebreak is neccessary with the library PHPWord?
Are there other solutions to solve the effort?*

Thanks a lot.

```
<?php
// ... setup the necessary includes

$html = '<h2 style="align: center">centered title</h2>';

$html .= '<p style="margin-top: 240pt;">Ordered (numbered) list:</p>';
$html .= '<ol>
            <li><p style="font-weight: bold;">List 1 item 1</p></li>
            <li>List 1 item 2</li>
            <ol>
                <li>sub list 1</li>
                <li>sub list 2</li>
            </ol>
            <li>List 1 item 3</li>
        </ol>';
        

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html, false, false);
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: My problem is that I dont know how to get the height oft the added $html in advance of rendering the docx so I can decide if a pagebreak is necessary.